# Calculating the variance of a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance

I have stumbled upon this question from my text book and I have been finding difficulty in understanding and solving it.

If X and Y are independent random variables with variances $σ_X^2 = 5$ and $σ_Y^2 = 3$. Find the variance of the random variable $Z = −2X + 4Y − 3$. Repeat afterwards this exercise, with $X$ and $Y$ not independent and $σ_{XY} = 1$.

Far as I know, if you have independent variables then $\textrm{var}(X+Y)= \textrm{var}(X)+\textrm{var}(Y)$ also $\textrm{var}(XY)=\textrm{var}(X)\textrm{var}(Y)$.

For the first question I just filled in 5 and 3:

$$Z=-2(5)+4(3)-3=-1$$

For the second question, I have absolutely no idea how to approach it.. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your first answer is wrong. You have to use the fact that $\operatorname{var}(aX)=a^2\operatorname{var}(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do this from the definitions. Note that
$$
Var X = \mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 = m_{X^2} - m_X^2,
$$
with $m$ denoting the expected value for a quick shorthand.

Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
Var (X+Y)
 &= \mathbb{E}\left[(X+Y)^2\right] - \mathbb{E}[X+Y]^2 \\
 &= \mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right] + \mathbb{E}\left[Y^2\right] + 2\mathbb{E}\left[XY\right]
  - m_X^2 - m_Y^2 - 2m_Xm_Y \\
 &= \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2 + 2(\mathbb{E}[XY] - m_X m_Y)
\end{split}
$$
Now, if $X,Y$ are independent,
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[XY]
 &= \iint_\mathbb{R^2} xy f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy \\
 &= \iint_\mathbb{R^2} xy f_X(x) f_Y(y) dxdy \\
 &= \left(\int_\mathbb{R} xf_X(x) \right)\left(\int_\mathbb{R} yf_Y(y) \right) \\
 &= m_X m_Y.
\end{split}
$$
This implies $Var(X+Y) = \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2$. When $X,Y$ are dependent, that's not necessarily true anymore.

In particular, if you let $X=Y$, it's easy to prove that
$$
Var(X+Y) = Var(X+X) = Var(2X) = 4\sigma_X^2.
$$

Can you finish this?

Comment: Thank you! However I still can't understand how I'd make use of the given that Var(XY)=1 to answer the second question

Comment: @DanieBader $\sigma_{XY}$ is not variance of $X\cdot Y$, but the *covariance*, i.e., $$\sigma_{XY} = \mathbb{E}[(X - m_X)(Y-m_Y)].$$

Comment: this makes a lot of sense now.. thank you so much!